# order value isnt showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm trying to have different `order_values` when someone presses the 3 `buttons`. But I really don't know what's going wrong with my code. When I press one of the three buttons, the `order_value` doesn't show up. I'm still new to Vue as well as JavaScript so can anyone please help.

```js
Vue.component("barista-template", {
  template: "#b-template",
  data: function() {
    return {
      order_type: "",
      order_value: "",
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showText() {
      if (this.order_type === '') return '';
      return 'One ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    choose: function(order_type) {
      this.order_type = order_type;

      if (this.order_type == "drip") {
        this.order_value = "$10";

      }
      if (this.order_type == "frenchpress") {
        this.order_value = "$20";
      }
      if (this.order_type == "aeropress") {
        this.order_value = "$30";
      }

    }
  },
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      showing: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>
<!--template for Barista-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
  <div>
    <div>{{showText}}</div>
    <button v-on:click="choose('Drip')">Drip</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('Frenchpress')">French Press</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('Aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Capitalization still matters with `==`

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: sorry don't understand ?

Comment: For instance in your if statment you used `drip`, but in function call (v-bind expression) you passed `Drip`, and then your statment return false and that block code doesn't execute.

Comment: You pass in `"Drip"` to the `choose` function, but `"Drip"` does not equal `"drip"`. You should pass in `"drip"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help thanksd, BelminBedak

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it has been pointed out, is that your the value cases are not matching. While it is an easy fix, a *better*(IMHO) way to prevent this from happening is to define an object that you can reference, rather than relying on the string values. This makes it waaaay easier to maintain and change. Check out how easy it is to add one more item.

```js
Vue.component("barista-template",{
  template: "#b-template",
  data: function () {
    return{
      order_type:"",
      order_value: "",
      menu: [
        {
          id: 'drip',
          name: 'Drip Coffee',
          cost: 10
        },
        {
          id: 'frenchpress',
          name: 'French Press',
          cost: 13
        },
        {
          id: 'aeropress',
          name: 'Aeropress',
          cost: 12.75
        },
        {
          id: 'omf',
          name: 'Orange Mocca Frappuccino',
          cost: "BLING BLING"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showText () {
      if(this.order_type === '') return 'Please make a choice...';
      return 'one ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
    }
  },
  methods: {
      choose: function (menu_item) {
          this.order_type = menu_item.name;
          this.order_value = "$"+menu_item.cost;
      }
  }

});

new Vue ({
  el:"#app",
  data:function () {
      return{
          showing:false
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>

<!--template for Barista-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
    <div>
    <div>{{showText}}</div>
    <button v-for="m in menu" :key="m.id" v-on:click="choose(m)">{{m.name}}</button>
  </div>
</script>
```